# Initializing static variable with nonconstant value

Tags: c, macros

From 21st century C book:

> Static variables, even those inside of a function, are initialized
>   when the program starts, before main, so you can’t initialize them
>   with a nonconstant value.
>
> ```
> //this fails: can't call gsl_vector_alloc() before main() starts
> static gsl_vector *scratch = gsl_vector_alloc(20);
> ```
>
> This is an annoyance, but easily solved with a macro to start at zero
>   and allocate on first use:
>
> ```
> #define Staticdef(type, var, initialization) \ 
> static type var = 0; \
> if (!(var)) var = (initialization);
>
> //usage:
> Staticdef(gsl_vector*, scratch, gsl_vector_alloc(20));
> ```

I don't understand what difference the macro made. Doesn't it do exactly the same thing after preprocessing?

---

Comment: Not a very safe recommendation by this book, but more a quick&dirty unsafe hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Doesn't it do exactly the same thing after preprocessing?

No, both not necessarily behave the same.

This initalisation is **guaranteed** to **run** only **once**:

```
static int i = 42; /* Initialisation */
```

This assignment

```
static int i = 0;
if (!i) /* line X */
  i = 42; /* Assignment */
```

is not, as **everytime** the program flow reaches line X and `i` equals `0` then `i` **is set** to `42` (again).

Examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int inew)
{
  static int i = 42;

  printf("%d\n", i);

  i = inew;
}

void bar(int inew)
{
  static int i = 0;
  if (!i)
    i = 42;

  printf("%d\n", i);

  i = inew;
}

int main(void)
{
  foo(43);
  foo(0);
  foo(44);

  printf("\n");

  bar(43);
  bar(0);
  bar(44);

  return 0;
}
```

Run it and see the difference:

```
42
43
0

42
43
42
```

Comment: Just a clarification, the `static int i = 0` still only runs once in the second example. After that the `if (!i)` will always be true in this example, so `i = 42` will always be called.

Comment: @Jite: I added an example.

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor only replaces the text, so that the end result of `Staticdef` macro is:

```
static gsl_vector *scratch = 0 ;
if (!(scratch )) scratch = (gsl_vector_alloc(20));
```

You can type that yourself if you wish or use the macro.

This is of course different than the incorrect version:

```
static gsl_vector *scratch = gsl_vector_alloc(20);
```

I recommend not using the macro as it cannot be wrapped in a do{}while, and only obfuscates the code.